# How to change aria-valuemax in angular2-material progressbar?

Tags: angular, angular-material

is there any way to change **`aria-valuemax="60"`** of **`Angular2-material progress bar`**?

By default internally **`aria-valuemax`** is set to **`100`**. Now using **`angular2-material progress bar`** I want to display **`time`** eg. **`second`**.

```
 <md-progress-circle 
              mode="determinate" 
              value= "+{{seconds}}" 
              aria-valuemax="60">            // I want to do something here.
</md-progress-circle>
```

**DEMO:** https://plnkr.co/edit/S6sjOVFkfFElt8rC1vQd?p=preview

I want my circle to complete a round when second becomes 60. In order to do it I need to set **`aria-valuemax=60`** but I don't know how to do it.

Any way to set it to 60 max value as I'm playing with time????

Answer (score 1):

Not sure but I think **`md-progess-circle`** is still being developed and yet not ready. As a work around, as usual you can play with logic and set it as show below.

```
<md-progress-circle 
              mode="determinate" 
              value= "+{{(seconds*100)/60}}">  //put my logic here
</md-progress-circle>
```

Hope this will help  others,

**https://plnkr.co/edit/6xNktSgO8KY0fIj1S6zb?p=preview**